# Como guardar e recuperar todas as Sessões de um usuário

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, session, servidor

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema no qual necessito recuperar todos os usuários logados ou com sessão ativa no servidor.

Contexto: Quando o usuário loga no sistema, além de criar a **session**, guardo na base de dados suas informações com data de *logon* e tempo da sessão.

```
Session["exemplo"] = exemplo;
```

Quando o usuário faz *logoff* eu derrubo a **session** e altero as informações na base de dados. Seguindo essa estrutura consigo ter "em mãos" todos os usuários logados. O problema que me ocorre é quando o usuário fica com tempo ocioso e a sessão automaticamente cai ou quando o usuário fecha o navegador. Dessa forma não consigo mais alterar o status do mesmo na base de dados.

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de recuperar todas as session ativas em um servidor, ou seja, recuperar todos os usuários que ainda estão logados no sistema e que suas **sessions** ainda não expiraram?

Alguém já conseguiu fazer algo semelhante?

Answer (score 5):

Você pode armazenar a lista de sessões ativadas como um item de Application. Assim:

```
public void Session_OnStart()
{
    if (Application["SessionList"] == null)
        Application["SessionList"] = new List<HttpSessionState>();

    var sl = (List<HttpSessionState>) Application["SessionList"];

    sl.Add(Session);

    Application["SessionList"] = sl;
}
```

Faça o mesmo, porém removendo a sessão, quando o evento `Session_OnEnd` ocorrer.

Comment: O tipo de dados List não aceita o tipo Session!

Comment: Você está correto, @MarcusUrbano - Eu utilizei a menção errada. Request.Session é do tipo HttpSessionState. Eu alterei o código de exemplo.

Comment: Fiz uns testes e mesmo assim só consigo enxergar o meu usuário na lista. Quando peço pra alguém logar no sistema é feita a mesma coisa pra ele, só que não é adicionado a lista de Session que eu enxergo. Preciso enxergar quando uma pessoa loga no sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a linha do @OnoSendai, você poderia usar um código assim no seu Global.asax:

```
public void Application_OnStart()
{
  Application["UsersOnline"] = 0;
}

public void Session_OnStart()
{
  Application.Lock();
  Application["UsersOnline"] = (int)Application["UsersOnline"] + 1;
  Application.UnLock();
}

public void Session_OnEnd()
{
  Application.Lock();
  Application["UsersOnline"] = (int)Application["UsersOnline"] - 1;
  Application.UnLock();
}
```